# Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, sdk

I have been looking for a solution for this issue for almost 2 days and I haven't found any. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 if any of you guys know how to solve this I will be grateful.
The error says:

***build failed***

**Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct?**

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0):

select the location of the Android SDK, in the menu bar go to Unity > Preferences, then click External Tools.

if you don't have android sdk for linux, you can take from this site:

https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

I hope it works.

Comment: first, thank u a lot for answering for my question,  anyway I already have SDK tools installed but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: is there any other solutions sir ??

Comment: mabye if you select the embedded sdk?
[link](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/PreferencesExternalToolsAndroid83.png)